# Bootstrap/Javascript/JQuery make buttons change color one a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have multiple (bootstrap)buttons in a page and I want only one of them to change color when clicked. Thus, If a button was previously clicked and received another color and now a new button is clicked the previous one should return to the normal color and the new one should change. 
(I hope I explained it right)

I now that it is possible with JQuery to change an elements class, ex. when clicked change from btn-primary to btn-success class(thus change color), but that requires the button to have an ID.

```
$("#td_id").attr('class', 'newClass');
```

1) So, how can I iterate through all the buttons, to check their class and change it if needed ?

2) Is there a more elegant solution ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the most elegant way to do this:-

```
$('.button').click(function() {
  $('.button').removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-primary ');
  $(this).addClass('btn-success').removeClass('btn-primary ');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Make use of a class. First `remove` the class from all the elements with `class="btn"` then add to the particular `button` which is clicked.

```
$('.btn').on('click',function(){
 $('.btn').removeClass('clr').addClass('clr2');
 $(this).removeClass('clr2').addClass('clr');
})
```

See ***[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6k89va99/1/).***

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="hello">
<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="hello">
<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="hello">
```

**JS**

```
// this will find all input with type button
// You can place any selector, in this case your button
// better put class name for all button, and target it name
$('input[type="button"]').on('click', function(){ 
  $('input[type="button"]').removeClass('btn-warning');
  $(this).toggleClass('btn-warning');
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/metallurgical/yr5yjaz9/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way. Just adjust the selector as needed to select the buttons you care about.

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('btn-primary').toggleClass('btn-success');
});
```

Comment: This will not change the class of previous button when a new button is clicked...

Comment: only when its added dynamically.

Comment: No Man, you are targeting the current element only (this), so it will not remove the class btn-success from previously clicked button..

Answer (score 0):

1- Give all your button a common class (ex : "unique-button")

2- When you click one button, iterate over all ("unique-button") button to remove class named "current"

3- Assign clicked button "current" class

4- With css give your ".unique-button.current" class the button color you want when clicked

This way, only one button will have clicked color, when an other is clicked, all button are reset and the clicked one gain the "current" class that give it the color.

```
$(".unique-button").on("click", function() {
    $(".unique-button").each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("current");
    });
    $(this).addClass("current");
```

});

// css
.unique-button.current { color: green; }